# What do civicrm extension "current usage" statistics indicate?

Tags: extension, civicrm.org

For example, [Mosaico CiviCRM Integration](https://civicrm.org/extensions/email-template-builder) shows "Current Usage: 3749". What does this number represent?

I imagine this is the number of live sites reporting that this extension has been in a certain state within a certain number of recent days, but what state (ever been installed / currently enabled / currently installed but disabled), and how many days (365 / 7 / 1)? Or is this number based on something more / less / else ?

Answer (score 1):

What a site sends back to civicrm.org is just this: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/506fffd478a7d322fbea786c35787c95a6dbe290/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php#L238-L240

name, enabled, version

One thing to note at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/506fffd478a7d322fbea786c35787c95a6dbe290/CRM/Utils/VersionCheck.php#L139 is that it's only sent back for beta and stable installs. Alpha dev sites do not send those stats back, but release candidate testing sites do.

Also note that it does this when its cache expires (3 days, or when cleared). It also up to a point depends on site cron.

Whether civicrm.org further scours the internet for more data to match it up to your birthdate, friends, and latest purchases I don't know - if you can find where the code for stable.php is at https://latest.civicrm.org/stable.php it will say what it does with it. It probably just stores it.

When it's displayed on an extension node, I believe it comes from the `update()` function at https://lab.civicrm.org/marketing/civicrm-website/-/blob/1f421835b1bc0ad2ce45a919215a6794955aa208/civiext/org.civicrm.civicrmorgstats/CRM/Civicrmorgstats/Utils/Extensions.php#L31-41, which in turn gets it from [https://stats.civicrm.org/json/ext/{extension](https://stats.civicrm.org/json/ext/%7Bextension) name}.

I believe that is somewhere at https://lab.civicrm.org/infra/stats-collection, but I would think just pulls it from whereever stable.php stored it.

So without seeing what is actually installed on civicrm.org, or knowing how often that `update()` function runs, half of this is guessing, but it's clear what a site sends back.

Comment: "... whether civicrm.org further scours the internet for more data to match it up to your birthdate, friends, and latest purchases I don't know ..." I dig the way you think, Demerit.

Comment: Trust no one, not even me. Don't even believe that statement.